# How to disable the automatic saving of *any* wireless networks?

Tags: wi-fi

With wifi settings in Android:

I know that you can disable "auto-connect" for a specific network.

I know that you can "forget" a specific network once Android has automatically added it to its list of "saved networks."

But is there a way to completely turn off the automatic adding/saving behavior so that it never saves any network?

I find it annoying (because, "Hey, I didn't tell you to do that!" and also a potential privacy problem -- using wifi monitoring tools, people can see what networks your phone is trying to connect to, and thus, what networks you have been connected to in the past.

Comment: Android does only actively try to connect to Wifis that are hidden (they don't send out an SSID broadcast). All the other (non-hidden) Wifis are detected by passively scanning thee SSID broadcast messages received by the phone. So for regular non-hidden Wifis there is no privacy issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any Device has to remember wifi credentials because if the signal fluctuates/disconnects, they need to reconnect.
It would be far more annoying to enter credentials every time the signal is lost than to "Forget" once when you don't need it.